# Optimum shower occupied retry delay

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

I cycle to work in an office with a single shower.  When the shower is occupied I set my stopwatch for 10 minutes.  When the stopwatch expires I trek back to the shower and try again.  Sometimes it is occupied again.

What is the optimum time to set my stopwatch to minimise the number of return trips?

I chose 10 minutes because I guessed that that's probably how long a reasonably quick shower takes.  But thinking about it perhaps a shorter delay might avoid me being beaten once the shower becomes free, whilst a longer delay would increase the likelihood that the initial occupier has left.

I realize there are loads of variables here that you might need to know so here's some details to get started with:

- All shower users use the same system when they arrive at work
- Shower users arrive at work at different times, but let's say between 9-10
- All shower users want to be out of their Lycra by the end of the morning (12) and to avoid interference with the lunchtime shower users.  Their co-workers want them out of their Lycra ASAP.  I'm not sure how to balance this requirement with the requirement to minimize the number of trips to the shower.  Suggestions?
- Shower users take between 8 and 16 minutes to shower
- There are between 4 and 10 shower users on a given day.
- I realize there are better ways to organize the shower queue!
- All shower user use the same retry delay

Comment: Just curious, is this an exercise or a real-life problem you're trying to model?

Comment: What is the distribution of the shower times, the interarrival times, and the number of arrivals?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a numerical modelization of your problem (Scilab code below) and used a Monte-Carlo method to compute the minimum.

At first, I found a decreasing function of the retry, which is compatible with the intuition that, the more you wait for the least you risk interacting

[image: Objective without penalisation]
Average total number of attempts to go to the shower as a function of the retry delay.

But then how can we respect the constraint: everyone is clean for lunch? Again we may graph the probability that the last one's shower is after 12:
[image]
Probability of having someone shower after 12, as a function of the retry delay.

We see that waiting for more than 16 min is a bad idea and that your 10 min delay isn't that bad... but we can test if it's a good idea to have a fixed idea of when you go to the shower. Let's randomize it too:
[image]
Average total number of attempts to go to the shower as a function of the retry delay.

Not so different from the first one is it? So you could have felt free to go shower whenever you wanted ;-)

```
function N=showerRetry(T)
Nbshower=grand(1,1,"uin",4,10);
Arrival=grand(1,Nbshower,"unf",0,60);
Showerduration=grand(1,Nbshower,"unf",8,16);//independant of the time you had to wait.
Nbtry=0;
Ttotry=gsort(Arrival,'g','i');
tfree=0;
nbclean=0;
while max(Ttotry)>0 do
    if tfree<Ttotry(nbclean+1) do //youpi je me lave
        nbclean=nbclean+1;
        tfree=Ttotry(nbclean)+Showerduration(nbclean);
        Ttotry(nbclean)=0;
    else//oh non j'attends
        Ttotry(nbclean+1)=Ttotry(nbclean+1)+T*grand(1,1,"unf",0.5,1.5)
        Ttotry=gsort(Ttotry,'g','i');
        Nbtry=Nbtry+1;
    end
end
//Nbtry=0//to get only the penalty
if tfree>60*3 then// si la dernière douche se termine après midi
    Nbtry=Nbtry+100 //forte pénalité
end
N=Nbtry//+exp(tfree-150)// smother penalization
endfunction


function M=Montecarlo(N,P)
    n=size(P,'*')//le nombre de périodes à tester
    Nb=zeros(1,n)
    for i=1:n
        for j=1:N
            Nb(i)=Nb(i)+showerRetry(P(i));
        end
        Nb(i)=Nb(i)/N
    end
    M=Nb
endfunction

P=[6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20,25,30];
T= Montecarlo(10000,P)
plot(P,T)
```